Does it reduce latency to deploy Google Cloud Run in multiple regions if your other Google products are located in one region?
A new feature in Google Cloud Run is that you can deploy your application to multiple regions. Is there a benefit to do so if your other Google Cloud products are only available in one region?
For example, let's say you have an API application with methods that query your Firestore database and return some data. Your Firestore database and Cloud Run application are located in London. Would it make sense to also deploy a your Cloud Run application to say, Sydney, to reduce latency for end users in Australia?
Since your application queries the Firestore database located in London, would it make any difference in latency for end users in Australia to hit your application in Sydney versus London? The Firestore query you do in your Sydney Cloud Run instance has to travel to London regardless to get the Firestore data.
Or is there some other optimizations on Google Cloud that will reduce latency because it is all in the same network?

The latency inside Google network is lower than outside. The traffic from Sydney to London should pass faster inside the network than through the open internet.
At the same time, usually there might be a global external application load balancer in front of the cloud run service, after which the traffic is going inside the Google network.
If everything is configured correctly.

If you want to go global and reduce the latency you must have processing unit (Cloud Run or something similar) and data (CLoud SQL, Firestore, Firebase,...) global. Cloud Run offer the possibility to easily deploy your processing unit in multi region, but if your data is stuck in a single one, the benefit will be low. Of course, as mentioned by @al-dann, you will benefit of the Google internal network and optimisation to go faster, but nothing can go faster that light speed (about 1ms for 300km)
